# Hw to show that $f_n(x)=\frac{(-1)^n}{nx+\sqrt{n}}$ converges on $\mathbb{R+}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Good evening!

I started to sutdy series of function and their convergence.
Yet, I'm still struggling to know how to show that a series converges.

I want to prove that the following series defined by $f_n(x)=\frac{(-1)^n}{nx+\sqrt{n}}$ defined on $\mathbb{R+}$ weakly-converges.

I said that:

- $f_n(0)=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\rightarrow 0$
- else $|f_n(x)|$ is decreasing and converges to 0 and therefore by the rule of Leibniz, $\sum f_n(x)$ weakly converges

But I'm wandering if this is sufficient, it seems a very weak argument to me just "seeing that it's decreasing and convergeing to 0" to conclude.

Comment: What do you call weak convergence in the context of series of functions? And what is the rule of Leibnitz? Note: I'm not an English native speaker.

Comment: "Convergence simple" in French? Did I mistook myself on what weak convergence was?

Comment: "Convergence simple" in French is pointwise convergence in English. And yes, as $\frac{1}{nx + \sqrt{n}}$ decreases monotonically and converges to $0$, you can apply the alternating series test to conclude that $\sum f_n(x)$ converges pointwise.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Leibnitz rule is sufficient to conclude pointwise convergence since for each $x$, the assumption of Leibnitz criterion is satisfies. 
If you want to be sure, write for $x\gt 0$, 
$$f_n(x)-\frac{(-1)^n}{nx}=(-1)^n\frac{nx-(nx+\sqrt n)}{(nx+\sqrt n)nx}=
-(-1)^n\frac 1{(nx+\sqrt n)\sqrt n x};$$
in this way, 
$$f_n(x)=\frac{(-1)^n}{nx}-(-1)^n\frac 1{(nx+\sqrt n)\sqrt n x},$$
and the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}f_n(x)$ follows from that of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{nx}$ (alternating series) and that of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^n 1/\left[(nx+\sqrt n)\sqrt n x\right]$, since 
$$\left|(-1)^n\frac 1{(nx+\sqrt n)\sqrt n x}\right|\leqslant \frac 1{n^{3/2}}.$$